# ASP.NET Server Controls - Show Hide Textbox based on Dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, jquery

What is the best way to show/hide a textbox or an entire div section based on a users selection from a dropdown? I don't believe its possible with server controls, so I would have to use regular client side HTML controls, correct? Thanks for any input. Would jQuery be the best option for this?

Based on the drop down selection, I want to be able to display the following Div, and by default hide the Div. Thoughts?:

```
 <div id="divLimitPrice">Limit Price<br />
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimitPrice" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupOrder">    </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with server controls the same as simple html controls. You only need to correct set the rendered client IDs of the control. Here is an example: (see the notes on the code for what I do)

```
function TriggerChange(me)
{
    // get the drop down control
    var cTheDropDown = jQuery("#<%=ddlControl.ClientID%>");

    // find the value of the selected one
    var SelValue = jQuery('option:selected', cTheDropDown).attr('value');

    // now do what you like with it
    if(SelValue == "open")
      jQuery("#divLimitPrice").show();
    else
      jQuery("#divLimitPrice").hide();
}
```

a shorter version of

```
function TriggerChange(me)
{
    // get the selected value from the drop down list
    //  and base on it, show or hide your div
    if(jQuery("#<%=ddlControl.ClientID%>").val() == "open")
      jQuery("#divLimitPrice").show();
    else
      jQuery("#divLimitPrice").hide();
}
```

And on control you add the trigger as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlControl" runat="server" onchange="TriggerChange(this);">
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to adapt the code and just having a slight issue.     <script type="text/javascript">
        function TriggerChange(me) {
            // get the drop down control
            var cTheDropDown = jQuery("#<%=ddPriceType%>");

            // find the value of the selected one
            var SelValue = jQuery('option:selected', cTheDropDown).attr('value');

            // now do what you like with it
            if (SelValue == "Limit")
                jQuery("#divLimitPrice").show();
            else
                jQuery("#divLimitPrice").hide();
        }
    </script>

Comment: does that script look correct? heres it the dropdown - <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPriceType" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupOrder" onchange="TriggerChange(this);">
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text ="Select a Price Type" /><asp:ListItem Value="Limit" text="Limit" /></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Here is the Div. Thank you! <div id="divLimitPrice" hidden="hidden">Limit Price<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimitPrice" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupOrder"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLimitPrice" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLimitPrice" ErrorMessage="This is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>

Comment: @gmatteson in this `jQuery("#<%=ddPriceType%>");` code you forget the ClientID,  `jQuery("#<%=ddPriceType.ClientID%>");`. Do the same and on the rest with ClientID. Now, I can not make it 100% perfect for you. See the code and try to understand what I do - is not just copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you you for the time @Aristo, appreciate it. Very helpful!